# microsoft-webdav-miniredir (ms word, excel etc.) digest auth and third-party apps integrations

Tags: authentication, ms-office, webdav, sabredav

i have a problem with authentication in ms-office programs that supports only digest authentication while using webdav-server.

I have a web app that can be on standalone version or as part of integration with third-party apps like LDAP or CRM-systems.
Good for me that i have no problems with LDAP-systems cause i can auth to them using login and password.
But i've trouble with OAuth authentication. Cause my app do not store any user's credentials from third-party apps that app integrates with.
Webdav clients don’t supports query params and i can't say to ms office apps send auth tokens as part of their request.
I'm using sabre/dav as webdav-server and nginx as reverse proxy.
How can i solve it?
thank you in advance